# Vanilla Javascript click on LI that contains a certain text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code that scans a webpage and outputs a special string, such as: `multus –a –um` And on the page it's executed on there are many `<LI>` elements containing texts like `multus –a –um` but, they are all different. I need a way to search the page for an element containing a certain string and then change some CSS on the `<LI>` element.

Example:

1. I run my code and get: `multus –a –um`
2. Search page for an `<LI>` element containing `multus –a –um`
3. Change background of element to `#17af50`

It need to be a function too, so I can run it easily

Comment: You will have to search through the dom and match its `textContent` attributes. What have you tried?

Comment: Loop `<li>` elements. What have you tried to solve Question?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the various Array methods.  They are fantastic.

```js
Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll("li"))
  .filter(function(item){ return item.innerText.indexOf("foo") !== -1; })
  .forEach(function(item){ item.parentNode.classList.add("highlight"); });
```

```css
.highlight { background-color: #17af50; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>foo bar</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can ad the highlight class to the parent of the `<li>`?

Comment: Just the parent **ul** or the **li** and the parent **ul**?

Comment: Just the **ul**, the parent